# Android Retrofit - Array data is empty

Tags: json, retrofit

I want to receive Json data from server using Retrofit.
Below is Data class and Json example.

After finish transfer the 'Page' object is returned from Response.body().
But inside it the array 'cards' has 'null' value.

How can I get the correct data?

[Page.java]===========

```
public class Page {
    public List<Cards> cards;
    public Page(List<Cards> cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }
    public class Cards {
        public String card_type;
        public Cards(String card_type) {
            this.card_type = card_type;
        }
    }
}
```

[Json example]===============

```
{
    "page": {
        "cards": [
          {
            "card_type": "text",
            "card": {
              "value": "Hello, Welcome to App!",
              "attributes": {
                "text_color": "#262626",
                "font": {
                  "size": 30
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "card_type": "title_description",
            "card": {
              "title": {
                "value": "Check out our App every week for exciting offers.",            
                "attributes": {
                  "text_color": "#262626",
                  "font": {
                    "size": 24
                  }
                }
              },
              "description": {            
                "value": "Offers available every week!",
                "attributes": {
                  "text_color": "#262626",
                  "font": {
                    "size": 18
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
       ]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all your model class not have get methods , your methods are setter not getter and its normal you cant get data without getter method , change your model like below :

at first , do not use inner class , made classes separate together

```
public class Page {
    public List<cards> cards;
    public List<cards> getCards() {
       return cards;
    }
```

---

```
public class cards {
    public String card_type;
    public String getCard_type() {
        return card_type;
    }

      public card card;
      public card getCard() {
            return card;
        }
 }
```

---

```
  public class card {
        public String value;
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    public attributes attributes;
       public String getAttributes() {
            return attributes;
        }
}
```

now this classes correct for your index 0 of cards , but your Json sample not have organization at next index ... but you can made title class or description class and add it to card class for get more data from any index of your list.